# Determining realloc() behaviour before calling it

Tags: c, memory-management

As I understand it, when asked to reserve a larger block of memory, the `realloc()` function will do one of three different things:

```
if free contiguous block exists
    grow current block
else if sufficient memory
    allocate new memory
    copy old memory to new
    free old memory
else
    return null
```

Growing the current block is a very cheap operation, so this is behavior I'd like to take advantage of. However, if I'm reallocating memory because I want to (for example) insert a char at the start of an existing string, I don't want `realloc()` to copy the memory. I'll end up copying the entire string with `realloc()`, then copying it again manually to free up the first array element.

Is it possible to determine what `realloc()` will do? If so, is it possible to achieve in a cross-platform way?

Comment: The last of your 3 cases is incorrect, realloc will return a null pointer if there is insufficient memory, not the pointer you passed it.

Comment: As Robert Gamble said - realloc() returns NULL on no memory.

Comment: I suppose it would be horribly picky to suggest that the first condition should be 'if free contiguous block exists and combined block is big enough' or something similar...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`realloc()`'s behavior is likely dependent on its specific implementation. And basing your code on that would be a terrible hack which, to say the least, violates encapsulation.

A better solution for your specific example is:

1. Find the size of the current buffer

   - Allocate a new buffer (with `malloc()`), greater than the previous one
   - Copy the prefix you want to the new buffer
   - Copy the string in the previous buffer to the new buffer, starting after the prefix
   - Release the previous buffer

Comment: This is just not logical, why don't use realloc and gain the performance improvement at least in some of the cases, your suggestion will memcpy always. He want to improve performance and avoid memcpy when not needed.

Comment: This is actually the solution I've currently implemented (though I overallocate each time in order to reduce the number of future reallocations).  As Ilya says, I was looking for a more optimal solution, but as you've pointed out, I've probably already got the best trade-off.

Comment: If you want to insert de char at the beginning, you'll have to use memmov() afeter reallocating the buffer...
If realloc() can't grow the current block, you'll copy the memory twice, once the realloc(), once the memmov()

Romulo's solution always copy the memory, but only once... ;)

Comment: Note that `memmove` is probably **a lot** slower than `memcpy`, especially when the offset is 1 byte, so allocating a new buffer where you can safely use `memcpy` is always best.

Comment: The problem with this is that you need to copy memory, so your system runs slower and slower as the amount allocated gets larger and larger.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, case 3 in the question (no memory) is wrong; `realloc()` will return NULL if there is no memory available [question now fixed].

Steve McConnell in 'Code Complete' points out that if you save the return value from `realloc()` in the only copy of the original pointer when `realloc()` fails, you've just leaked memory.  That is:

```
void *ptr = malloc(1024);
...
if ((ptr = realloc(ptr, 2048)) == 0)
{
    /* Oops - cannot free original memory allocation any more! */
}
```

Different implementations of realloc() will behave differently.  The only safe thing to assume is that the data will *always* be moved - that you will always get a new address when you realloc() memory.

As someone else pointed out, if you are concerned about this, maybe it is time to look at your algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

Would storing your string backwards help?

Otherwise...
just malloc() more space than you need, and when you run out of room, copy to a new buffer. A simple technique is to double the space each time; this works pretty well because the larger the string (i.e. the more time copying to a new buffer will takes) the less often it needs to occur.

Using this method you can also right-justify your string in the buffer, so it's easy to add characters to the start.

Answer (score 0):

No <strike>- and if you think about it, it can't work. Between you checking what it's going to do and actually doing it, another process could allocate memory.</strike>
In a multi-threaded application this can't work. Between you checking what it's going to do and actually doing it, another thread could allocate memory.

If you're worried about this sort of thing, it might be time to look at the data structures you're using to see if you can fix the problem there. Depending on how these strings are constructed, you can do so quite efficiently with a well designed buffer.

Comment: Another process will allocate it in his address space so it's not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible in cross platform way.
[Here](http://www.google.com/codesearch?hl=en&q=show:4f2oPw-25m8:NZvFhxd9P74:55xbVtXJ6eg&sa=N&ct=rd&cs_p=http://freshmeat.net/redir/uclibc/20616/url_bz2/uClibc-0.9.28.1.tar.bz2&cs_f=uClibc-0.9.29/libc/stdlib/malloc/realloc.c) is the code for ulibc implementation that might give you a clue how to do itin platform dependent way, actually it's better to find glibc source but this one was on top of google search :)

Answer (score 0):

If [obstacks](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Obstacks.html#Obstacks) are a good match for your memory allocation needs, you can use their [fast growing](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Extra-Fast-Growing.html#Extra-Fast-Growing) functionality. Obstacks are a feature of glibc, but they are also available in the [libiberty](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libiberty/) library, which is fairly portable.

Answer (score 0):

Why not keep some empty buffer space in the left of the string, like so:

```
char* buf = malloc(1024);
char* start = buf + 1024 - 3;
start[0]='t';
start[1]='o';
start[2]='\0';
```

To add "on" to the beginning of your string to make it "onto\0":

```
start-=2;
if(start < buf) 
  DO_MEMORY_STUFF(start, buf);//time to reallocate!
start[0]='o';
start[1]='n';
```

This way, you won't have to keep copying your buffer every single time you want to do an insertion at the beginning.

If you have to do insertions at both the beginning and end, just have some space allocated at both ends; insertions in the middle will still need you to shuffle elements around, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach is to use a linked list. Have each of your data objects allocated on a page, and allocate another page and have a link to it, either from the previous page or from an index page. This way you know when the next alloc fails, and you never need to copy memory.